# Find and replace with PowerShell based on the next line

Tags: powershell, replace

I'm trying to find and replace via PowerShell based on what's on the next line of the line I want to replace. For example, the following text file:

```
blahblah 
flimflam 
zimzam
```

If the line after `blahblah` is `flimflam`, replace `blahblah` with `new stuff`

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($myFile.FullName);
$FileContents=$reader.ReadToEnd()
$reader.Close()


if(the line after "blahblah" == "flimflam") #pseudo code
{
    $FileContents=$FileContents.Replace("blahblah","new stuff")
}
```

If the next line is anything other than `flimflam`, do nothing.

One idea I had was to replace "blahblah n` flimflam" with "new stuff", but I can't get it to work. I think I might be onto something with including the new line character though.

Comment: I added the #pseudo code comment to that line specifically, because it's the only pseudo code line.

Comment: OK you've put it back now, sorry that part of my edit was not what you wanted.

Comment: What should happen when the input contains twice `flimflam` (after each other), e.g.: `'blahblah', 'flimflam', 'flimflam', 'zimzam'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- While your use of `System.IO.StreamReader` works, it's generally easier to use `Get-Content -Raw` to read a file into memory *in full*, as a *single, multi-line* string.

  - If performance is a concern, you can still use .NET types directly, in which case `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($myFile.FullName)` is a much simpler alternative - although if there's any performance gain to be had over `Get-Content -Raw` at all, it is probably insignificant.
  - To specify the input file's encoding explicitly, use `Get-Encoding -Encoding <encoding>` / `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($myFile.FullName, <encoding>)`,
- The `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method is limited to *literal* string replacement, so advanced matching such as limiting matches to a *full line* is not an option.

  - Use PowerShell's regex-based `-replace` operator instead.
  - To prevent confusion with PowerShell's string expansion (string interpolation) in double-quoted (`"..."`) strings, it's generally preferable to use `-replace` with *single-quoted* (`'...'`) strings, which PowerShell treats as literals, so you can focus on *regex* constructs in the string.

```
PS> $FileContents -replace '(?m)^blahblah(?=\r?\nflimflam$)', 'new stuff'
new stuff
flimflam
zimzam
```

- `(?m)` uses inline option `m` (multi-line)  to make anchors `^` / `$` match the start / end of *each line* (instead of the string as a whole).
- `(?=...)` is a look-ahead assertion that matches without including the matching part in the overall match, so that it doesn't get replaced.
- `\r?\n` is a platform-agnostic way to match a *newline* sequence / character: CRLF (`\r\n`) on Windows, LF-only (`\n`) on Unix-like platforms.

Comment: What if I know that it contains blah and want to replace blah only? So can I replace a substring with this method?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, you can replace substrings with this method. I encourage you to ask a new question with your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

With a RegEx with a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can replace the previous line without even knowing the content of that line:

```
(Get-Content .\SO_53398250.txt -raw) -replace "(?sm)^[^`r`n]+(?=`r?`nflimflam)","new stuff"|
 Set-Content .\SO_53398250_2.txt
```

See the RegEx explained on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kVLqgQ/1) (with different escaping `n => \n)

Answer (score 0):

This questions asks for a reusable cmdlet that supports streaming as much as possible...

## `Replace-String`

```
Function Replace-String {
    [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([String[]])]Param (
        [String]$Match, [String]$Replacement, [Int]$Offset = 0,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True)][String[]]$InputObject
    )
    Begin {
        $Count = 0
        $Buffer = New-Object String[] ([Math]::Abs($Offset))
    }
    Process {
        $InputObject | ForEach-Object {
            If ($Offset -gt 0) {
                If ($Buffer[$Count % $Offset] -Match $Match) {$Replacement} Else {$_}
            } ElseIf ($Offset -lt 0) {
                If ($Count -ge -$Offset) {If ($_ -Match $Match) {$Replacement} Else {$Buffer[$Count % $Offset]}}
            } Else {
                If ($_ -Match $Match) {$Replacement} Else {$_}
            }
            If ($Offset) {$Buffer[$Count++ % $Offset] = $_}
        }
    }
    End {
        For ($i = 0; $i -gt $Offset; $i--) {$Buffer[$Count++ % $Offset]}
    }
}
```

### Syntax

```
$InputObject | Replace-String [-Match] <String to find>
                              [-Replacement] <Replacement string to use>
                              [-Offset] <Offset relative to the matched string>
```

### Examples:

Replace the found string:

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' | Replace-String Three X 0
One
Two
X
Four
Five
```

Replace the string prior the found string:

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' | Replace-String Three X -1
One
X
Three
Four
Five
```

Replace the second string prior the found string:

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' | Replace-String Three X -2
X
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

Replace the string after the found string:

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' | Replace-String Three X 1
One
Two
Three
X
Five
```

Replace the second string after the found string:

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' | Replace-String Three X 2
One
Two
Three
Four
X
```

Replace the strings prior the (two) strings that contains a `T`:

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' | Replace-String T X -1
X
X
Three
Four
Five
```

Replace the strings after the (two) strings that contains a `T`:

```
'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' | Replace-String T X 1
One
Two
X
X
Five
```

Specific to the question:

```
'blahblah', 'flimflam','zimzam' | Replace-String 'flimflam' 'new stuff' -1
new stuff
flimflam
zimzam
```

### Parameters

**`-InputObject <String[]>`** (From pipeline)
A stream of strings to match and replace

**`-Match <String>`**
The string to match in the stream.
Note that the `-Match` operator is used for this parameter which means that it support regular expressions. If the whole string needs to match, use [start line and end line anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions), e.g.: `-Match '^Three$'`.

**`-Replacement <String>`**
The string to use for replacing the target(s).

**`-Offset <Int> = 0`**
The offset to string relative to the matched string(s) to replace. The default is `0`, meaning: replace the matched string(s).

### Background

A little background on the programming in this cmdlet:

- The [Input Processing Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-6) (`Begin {...}`, `Process {...}`, `End {...}` are used to pass the strings as fast as possible through the cmdlet and release them for the next cmdlet in the pipeline. This cmdlet is designed for the middle of a pipeline (e.g. `Get-Content $myFile | Replace-String A B 1 | ...`). To leverage from the pipeline:

  - Avoid brackets (like: <del>`($List) | Replace-String A B`</del>
  - Avoid assigning the output (like: <del>`$Array = ... | Replace-String A B`</del>
  - Avoid parameters that read in the whole content (as <del>`Get-Content -Raw`</del>)
- If both cases (replacing behind -using a negative offset- or ahead -using a positive offset-), a buffer is required of the size of the offset (`$Buffer = New-Object String[] ([Math]::Abs($Offset))`)
- To speed up the process, the script cycles through the buffer (`$Buffer[$Count % $Offset]`) rather than shifting the contained items
- `If ($Count -ge -$Offset) {...` will hold the first number of input strings (equal to the offset) as it can only later been determined whether an input string needs to be replaced or not
- In the end (`End {...`), if the `$Offset` is negative, the buffer (that contains the rest of the input strings) is being released. In other words, a negative offset (e.g. `-offset -$n`) will buffer `$n` strings and cause the output to run `$n` strings behind the input stream